# Notarise an DMG containing a application and plist file

Tags: xcode, code-signing, dmg

I have a DMG that contains an Installer Application and a plist file which contains some preferences for installation. I have a use-case wherein i will need 50 to 60 different dmg with different preferences. Now as per catalina specification i will need to notarise my All 50 to 60 dmg. Is there any way to avoid this?

One way i can think of is notarising only Installer Application and avoid notarizing dmg, but i am not sure if gatekeeper will block dmg if it’s not notarized.